# How to set an optional reset_password_keys for Devise

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In a Rails app, the config Devise file has a reset_password_keys option.  Is there a way to make one of the keys optional?

Currently I have this setting `config.reset_password_keys = [ :email, :account_id ]`.

I would like to make the :account_id an optional key if there is no account_id present.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for me:

`#Admin.rb
devise :database_authenticatable, :encryptable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :reset_password_keys => [:email]`

Answer (score 0):

There's an [entry](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address#allow-users-to-recover-their-password-or-confirm-their-account-using-their-username) on Devise's wiki that deals with that.
I'd suggest you do the following:

```
# on config/initializers/devise.rb:
config.reset_password_keys = [ :email, :account_id ]

# on User model
def self.find_first_by_auth_conditions(warden_conditions)
  conditions = warden_conditions.dup
  where(account_id: conditions[:account_id], email: conditions[:email]).first
end

# on passwords/new.html.erb
<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %></p>
<%= f.label :account_id %><br />
<%= f.text_field :account_id %></p>
```

Comment: I have two models that can click on forgot my password, User.rb and Admin.rb. When a User is resetting their password they need to have the email and account id required but when the Admin logs in only email can be used since it doesn't have an account id.

Comment: Is there a way to set the config.reset_password_keys equal to different keys based on the model? For User, config.reset_password_keys = [:email, :account_id] and for Admin config.reset_password_keys = [:email].

Comment: Oh.. Now I get it. For User.rb both email and account_id are required. I haven't tried this, but I think you'll have to override `.find_first_by_auth_conditions` on `User.rb` and `Admin.rb`. I think you can stick with your array [:email, :account_id] and just ignore `account_id` for the Admin model.

Comment: You can use `config.scoped_views = true` and then `rails g devise:views` to copy different templates for user and admin.

Comment: Actually, I don't think Admin will need any overriding as it behaves like the default use case. I updated the User model to set both account_id and email as required attributes.

Comment: I was able to override it on the Admin.rb like you said. Thanks.